# SNIReadSync executing between 120-500 ms for a simple query. What do I look for?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net, c#-2.0

I am executing a simple query against SQL Server 2005:

```
protected static void InitConnection(IDbCommand cmd) {
        cmd.CommandText = "set transaction isolation level read uncommitted ";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
    }
```

Whenever I profile with dotTrace 3.1, it claims that SNIReadSync method is taking between 100 - 500 ms.

What sort of things do I need to be looking for in order to get this time down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested, but would wonder if you have the same issue if you used a TransactionScope with the options of IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted.  You would have to encapsulate your complete set of calls and that should negate the need for this statement. I realize that this statement is not your basic concern, but in general.

Another thing that you can do is to create a DBConnectionScope class (or leverage a trusted vendor's class) and cut down on the total number of connections that are opened.

Comment: Cort we actually identified this as a solution to the problem.  Another possibility was to prepend the set isolation level query to any query that runs, since it doesn't matter if the query runs in separate batches or not.

Comment: There is another possibility as well:  Snapshot isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that connection pooling is enabled or you will receive a significant penalty each time a connection is opened.  In your connection string set Pooling=True, or remove any reference to pooling. I believe the default is enabled.

This fixed the issue for me. Hope it helps for you and others.

Comment: Yes, connection pooling is enabled.  I took some profile traces using dotTrace in our peak on a server today...And SNIReadSync seems to be the biggest monster :)... Looks like implementing a distributed caching server could help this.