# SNIReadSync taking long time

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have delay our application. database is responding in 300 ms and then the total response time is 6.4 sec . 6.1 sec is spend in SNIReadSync  method. i totally understand the comment about the cached plan in the link: [Ado.net performance:What does SNIReadSync do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354346/ado-net-performancewhat-does-snireadsync-do) . what i am not understanding is if the cache plan was wrong shouldn’t it take more time at data base .

here it is taking time in reading the data from database to appserver.